# NSButton with clickable image and text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I've created an NSButton (see code below).  The button displays the way I want (borderless, with image above text).  If I click the text portion of the button the button will press down and call it's action.  If I click the image portion of the button then absolutely nothing happens.  How can I make the image portion of the NSButton clickable?  I'm sure I can subclass the NSButtonCell to make this work, but I don't understand why that would be necessary.

```
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
[button setBezelStyle:NSRegularSquareBezelStyle];
[button setBordered:YES];
[button setImagePosition:NSImageAbove];
[button setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
[button setTitle:@"Button Title"];
[button setTarget:self];
[button setAction:@selector(buttonAction:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The image on the button itself. No need to make it clickable. Your click event will be caught by buttonAction.

You only need to  show the animation that image got clicked. For that, you need another inverse image. And track the mouse down event, when you click down show the other image, when you release mouse (mouse up) show the default image.

This will give the feel of click on the image.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct.  Currently when I click the text portion of the button, the image dims as if it's being clicked.  So basically clicking the text portion is providing the proper feedback to the user that it is being clicked.  But if you click the image portion of the button then that visual feedback is not presented.  This is the case regardless of whether or not I populate the alternateImage property of the NSButton.

Comment: No, clicking the image portion of the button is doing nothing.. No animation and the target's action is not being called.  Clicking the text portion of the button animates the image (by displaying the alternate image) and calls the target's action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some other view overlaps your button's image? In code above, of course if you provide appropriate button frame, all works fine (for both, bordered and borderless button). Try it in clean project.